# Using jqueries validation plugin, how to send an error from the server side to the client side?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a custom validation check that I perform on the server sidie (.net mvc).

If it fails, I want to notify the user with a message next to the input box (just how jqueries validation plugin works out of box).

Is there a built in function (in the validation plugin) I can call to do this?

**Update**
The solution would ideally be using the plugin itself, maybe there is a method call I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is [an example](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/captcha/index.php) of this.

You basically `rules: {FIELD: {remote: "URL"}}`, then on validation a call is made to `URL?FIELD=value` and on the server you return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source project called [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/) that does this. Here's an excerpt from the project home page:

> Project Description xVal is a validation framework for ASP.NET MVC
>   applications. It makes it easy to link
>   up your choice of server-side
>   validation mechanism with your choice
>   of client-side validation library,
>   neatly fitting both into ASP.NET MVC
>   architecture and conventions. Features
>
> - Define your validation rules using attributes on model properties,
>     e.g.,
>
>   [Required] [StringLength(50)] public
>     string Name { get; set; }
>
> (Or, if you prefer, you can supply
>   rules programatically or you can just
>   hard-code them in specific views)
>
> - Designed to fit into ASP.NET MVC conventions for handling form posts
>     and storing and retrieving error
>     information in ModelState
> - Use your choice of server-side validation framework. Out of the box,
>     xVal lets you use .NET 3.5's built-in
>     DataAnnotations classes or Castle
>     Validator (or both). If you want to
>     use something different, you can
>     create your own provider just by
>     implementing IRulesProvider.
> - Use your choice of client-side validation library. Out of the box,
>     xVal lets you use jQuery Validation or
>     ASP.NET's native client-side
>     validation library (a.k.a.
>     WebUIValidation.js, as used by
>     WebForms). Or, use any other
>     client-side validation library by
>     writing a plug-in to configure it
>     using xVal's standard JSON rules
>     description format.
> - Supports localized error messages using resource files. Vary
>     the language of your validation
>     messages according to the current
>     thread's culture.
> - Add custom validation logic that runs both on the server and on the
>     client, either by subclassing an
>     existing rule or by referencing a
>     custom JavaScript function

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom validation function and couple it with an ajax call. In this case the ajax call will return the text 'true' or 'false'.

```
var customFunction = function(value, element, param) {
    var isValid = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/something',
        data:{value: value},
        success: function(data, textStatus) {isValid = data;},
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false
    });
    return isValid;
};

$.validator.addMethod("customFunction", customFunction, "That isn't valid.");

$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        fieldname: {
            customFunction: true
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit**: Actually, use the remote method that svinto mentions instead. I didn't even know that existed. I'm a fool.